# Bleach in water only good for one day?

Tags: water

In this time of COVID-19 our establishment is being told by government sources to spray down surfaces with a 9:1 water bleach solution, and then told to throw it out within 24 hours. What makes it less effective when we have over the counter products with bleach in them that obviously sit on the shelves for months and years?

Answer (score 2):

Commercial liquid chlorine bleaches, used in the laundry, are stabilized with sodium hydroxide at high pH. When you dilute the bleach in water, the alkali concentration also decreases. As a result, the active ion (hypochlorite $\ce{OCl-}$) slowly begins to decompose to the chloride ion (the common salt).

Answer (score 2):

The Chlorox website says solution of 1 part of Chlorox Regular bleach in 24 parts of water is registered with the US EPA as a disinfectant. Its effectiveness is assured by making a fresh solution daily.

Chlorox says it should be stored between at about room temperature or cooler, and the undiluted commercial product has a shelf life of 6 to 12 months from the date of manufacture (which I assume can be obtained from the manufacturer using the dot code printed on the bottle). Undiluted bleach degrades at a rate of 20% per year until it is all gone. And a 1:10 bleach solution has a shelf life of 24 hours.

So, if you make up 1 part in 24 daily - perhaps this is good for an 8-10 hour shift, but if you want a whole 24 hours, make up a 10% solution. And fresh bleach is good for 6 months or 12, but no differentiation is made between 5% and 8% hypochlorite products (this concentrated version is also available). Well, even after a year, the bleach is 80% of its original strength, so you could continue to use it at a higher dose: 1.25 parts in 24, or 12.5% for 24 hours.

It all seems kind of vague, but you could analyze the bleach with H2O2 and collect the gas, or titrate with KI and then thiosulfate. But that seems labor-intensive. One thing to take away from the data is that bleach doesn't suddenly become ineffective, just less effective, so if you follow the guidelines set by authorities who have done the testing, you will kill all the bugs and be held blameless if one or two manage to escape (they will probably be weakened).